# JSON.retrocycle only converts some references

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a array of objects some of whom have cyclic references in them. So I used JSON.decycle upon sending the object via JSON and JSON.retrocycle on the other end.

Something like this:

```
var refactor_data = JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(event.data));
```

The problem is that some of the ojects in 'refactor_data' have the JSONPath references transformed while other don't and I can't figure out why.

The objects are fairly large but if needed I'll try to provide a sample.

EDIT:
Here is a sample of an OK object: http://pastebin.com/1hZDCipn
And here is a sample of an broken object: http://pastebin.com/PfYCkrGt

EDIT2:
I think the ones that have the references 'replaced' are actually the originals and retrocycle actually doesn't do anything on any of them. Could this be because they are too 'deep' within the object structure ?

<strike>EDIT3: I've tried to run in FireBug the eval that retrocycle should run:</strike>   (I think it's normal for this not to work)

EDIT4: I've added a console.log within the JSON.retrocycle function and eval() return the correct object but the returned JSON and original JSON are unaltered.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you post the right examples in your EDIT?  That doesn't look like Javascript to me.

Comment: Could you post the data in a more standard format?

JSON works recursively, so it shouldn't matter how deep an element is.

Comment: That's the output that I get in PHP after json_decode(), but it's the same with what I get in Firebug. As for a more standard format, what do you have in mind ?

Comment: Can you show an example of the bad decycled event.data object prior to retrocycling?

Comment: It's pretty much the data in the second example (http://pastebin.com/PfYCkrGt), with $ref still in place such: '$[11]["LegList"][0]["ItenaryList"][0]["Ar"]'. Besides outputting it from PHP I can't think of an elegant way of showing you an example.

Comment: Could you show these example data structures in JSON (i.e., the input to json_decode()) rather than PHP dumps?  That would make it far easier to help and if you can pretty-print it, that's even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JSON-js cycle.js retrocycle function](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/ad6079cbd8dc362a3cc42e1f97c01aa5ccd48bfe/cycle.js) does not expect a path to have an array index greater than 9.

One example path that is not being retrocycled is:

```
$[11]["LegList"][0]["ItenaryList"][0]["Ar"]
```

A similar path that does get retrocycled is:

```
$[9]["LegList"][0]["ItenaryList"][0]["Ar"]
```

If you look at the cycle.js code, you will see that in order for a path to be retrocycled, it must validate against a regular expression.

```
// [...] A PATH is expected to be
// reasonably short. A PATH is allowed to belong to a very restricted subset of
// Goessner's JSONPath.

// So,
// var s = '[{"$ref":"$"}]';
// return JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(s));
// produces an array containing a single element which is the array itself.

var px =
    /^\$(?:\[(?:\d?|\"(?:[^\\\"\u0000-\u001f]|\\([\\\"\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}))*\")\])*$/;
```

In the px regular expression, only one digit array indexes are allowed, not two.
Since the path does not match the pattern, it will not replace the reference.

You could try using a local copy of cycle.js and changing the px regular expression to:

```
var px = /^\$(?:\[(?:\d+|\"(?:[^\\\"\u0000-\u001f]|\\([\\\"\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}))*\")\])*$/;
```

Note the difference from the previous regular expression: we are saying that we will now allow one or more digits in array indices.  This is accomplished by replacing the single ? character after the first d with a +.

**Edit:** Newer versions of the [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/commits/master/cycle.js) retrocycle function now allow array indices that are greater than 9.

Comment: I gave it a go and this is what it says:  


    Invalid regular expression: /^\$(?:[(?:\d+?|\"(?:[^\\"\u0000-\u001f]|\([\\"/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}))\")])$/: Unmatched ')'

Comment: @Brayn sorry the regex I suggested was missing a few characters because I did not have it formatted as a code block.  It is the same as the existing regex except for a + inserted after the d.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: YAY, that seems to have done it. Would you be so kind as to give me some more details on exactly what was the problem ?

Thanks forever, I couldn't find an answer anywhere!